# Crystal Report refresh Data

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, odbc

I am developing an application in .net windows form, the problem is this.

I have a CystalReportViewer Linked to a procedure with input parameters, ODBC connection, the problem or question is how to update the report without having to type in the parameters that are already shipping from code

```
nformeAvanceObra objReport = new InformeAvanceObra();  //  Object .rpt report
objReport.SetParameterValue("CodCoti", CodCotizacion);//parameter that I send to Procedure
objReport.SetParameterValue("Fecha2", Fecha);// parameter that I send to Procedure
crystalReportViewer.ReportSource = objReport; //asigno al viewer.
```

could help me or giving me an idea of how to accomplish what I want? , Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I may have not understood your question correctly.. What you mean by "shipping from code"?

If Crystal Reports is running your procedure, then your Crystal Reports should be the one sending the parameters to your procedure. If you require parameters to run that procedure, yes you will need to provide this parameters to your Crystal Reports Report.

If you want to fix parameters to a certain value, then you don't have to send it over from your code. But certainly you will need to change your report for that!

Example how to send parameters:

```
ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();

ParameterFields paramFields = new ParameterFields();
// ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

ParameterField paramField = new ParameterField();
ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
paramField.Name = "@Dept";
paramDiscreteValue.Value = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
paramFields.Add(paramField);

paramField = new ParameterField(); // <-- This line is added
paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();  // <-- This line is added
paramField.Name = "@Name";
paramDiscreteValue.Value = TextBox2.Text.ToString();
paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
paramFields.Add(paramField);

CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;
reportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport.rpt"));
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument;
reportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "sa", "OPWFMS-7KYGZ7SB", "test");
```

Comment: If the assigned parameters from another form, when you open the crystal report, I want to refresh the report parameters keep taking me to send it (as described above), but I keep asking the parameters

Comment: @DeibisJoel take a look at this example. I updated my answer just now.